# SQL Using Full Text Search

Tags: sql

So i have a bunch of products.. and I have a Full text search table, how can I query , please correct my code.. if i want to do somethin like

```
SELECT myID, myName, myAddress FROM myTable where myID IN (Select myIDFullText From myFullTextTable where FREETEXT(*,'Joe jane'))
```

This is wrong but I cant figure out how to make it work.

Thank you

Comment: "This is wrong" -- how is it wrong? What is it (not) doing that you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to do something like:

```
SELECT myID, myName, myAddress FROM myTable where myID IN (Select myIDFullText From myFullTextTable WHERE CONTAINS(myName, 'Some Text'))
```

This link ought to help as well http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142547.aspx